# Troubleshooting (managed) memory leaks on an azure web site

Tags: azure, memory-leaks, azure-web-app-service, kudu

There's a lovely [blog post here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/12/20/investigating-memory-leaks-in-azure-web-sites-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx) that tells you how to go about looking for memory leaks in an azure web site..

Trouble is, things have moved on, and azure doesn't support giving you a gcdump as described in that post (The URL fro grabbing a gcdump is not valid).

What I want to do is just to work out where a potential memory leak is happening - I've tried:

1. Using Kudu, I can grab a minidump (I can also grab a minidump WITH memory heap as described [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Process-Threads-list-and-minidump-gcdump-diagsession)). I've done this but I can't work out what to do with it, if I open it in VS 2015 then I get a rather useless "MiniDump File Summary", like this: [image]
2. I can "profile" the web app, with the "start profiling" button in the Kudu process explorer.. I can then open the resulting diagsession file in VS, but it only tracks CPU utilization, not memory heap information.

Help!

Answer (score 3):

You can get your memory dumps automatically analyzed by the Web App Support Portal, which could save you some debugging time.

Go to `https://<yoursitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/support` and click "Analyze" -> "Diagnose Now" and wait for the analysis to complete (it takes a couple minutes)

Comment: Thanks, I've not seen the support stuff before! But.. when I did this, everything else worked apart from the memory logs, which errored with: Tool did not generate any logs or records: MemoryDumpCollector :(

Comment: legend. saved me hours hunting for where they'd moved it all to now